# Rails image upload issue with Paperclip and ImageMagick - Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

When I tried to upload an image in my Rails app I got the error message:

```
Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.
```

I installed ImageMagick from [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

The steps I followed were:

1. added paperclip in gemfile
2. ran `bundle install`
3. added `has_attached _file` in my model
4. ran `rails g paperclip post image`

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: What is your version of ImageMagick. If you are using ImageMagick 7.x.x.x, then the command has changed to "magick identify" (without the quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify the ImageMagick path on your environment file? (development.rb or production.rb).

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "YOUR_IMAGEMAGICK_PATH"
```

For me (linux server) just inserted this line inside my config/environments/production.rb and the problem was gone!

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "YOUR_IMAGEMAGICK_PATH"
```